# Starting and stopping Twisted connections

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, twisted.internet, twisted.client

I'm writing application that uses python Twisted API (namely `WebSocketClientProtocol, WebSocketClientFactory, ReconnectiongClientFactory`. I want to wrap client factory into reader with following interface

```
class Reader: 
    def start(self):
        pass
    def stop(self):
        pass
```

Start function will be used to open connection (i.e. connect on ws api and start reading data), while `stop` will stop such connection.

My issue is that if I use `reactor.run()` inside `start`, connection starts and everything is OK, but my code never goes pass that line (looks like blocking call to me) and I cannot execute subsequent lines (include `.stop` in my tests).

I have tried using variants such as `reactor.callFromThread(reactor.run)` and `reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)` or even excplicity calling `Thread(target=...)` but none seems to work (they usually don't build protocol or open connection at all).

Any help or guidelines on how to implement `Reader.start` and `Reader.stop` are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `reactor.run` inside `Reader.start` then `Reader` will be a difficult component to use alongside other code.  Your difficulties are just the first symptom of this.

Calling `reactor.run` and `reactor.stop` are the job of code responsible for managing the lifetime of your application.  Put those calls somewhere separate from your WebSocket application code.  For example:

```
r = Reader()
r.start()
reactor.run()
```

Or better yet, implement [a twist(d) plugin](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tap.html) and let twist(d) manage the reactor for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was afraid I'd have to put `reactor.run` and `reactor.stop` outside scope of the `Reader`.
Would you care to give me some pointers about implementing twisted plugin approach?

Comment: Sure thing, doc link added.

Comment: Great, I'll check it out.